# How to install language packages and .sty for lyx in ubuntu

Tags: lyx, ubuntu

I'm working in ubuntu 15.10 some files which I made in windows and lyx doesn't compile them. The error results are:

```
Package babel Error. You haven't specified a language option

Undefined control sequence

Undefined control sequence

Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

LaTeX Error: File 'stmaryrd.sty' not found
```

However, if I change the language from spanish to english, the errors vanish and only stay the last one (`LaTeX Error: File 'stmaryrd.sty' not found`)

I would like to know how to solve these problems installing the corresponding packages in ubuntu.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example? Please read this: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Welcome! We need complete error messages, too. The errors will have included the control sequences which are undefined. We don't know what those are, but you do if you read the output.

Answer (score 18):

I haven't found `texlive-math-extra` via apt, but I found the
package `texlive-science` that contains the St. Mary road symbols (see [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-science)).

So I simply made

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-science
```

And it solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The `stmaryrd.sty` file is part of the `texlive-math-extra` package. Try installing the package and see if that doesn't solve the "File not found" problem.